# Invalid HTTP header field value in flutter

Tags: flutter

I receive this error `Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid HTTP header field`  when my header value contain accent: village_name=moapé.

How to encode header to avoid this. This my code:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "cookie": cookies};

http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I create a function use uri.encodecomponent to solve my problem this my code:

````
convert(value){
    /*
      Convertir les valeurs pour eviter que les accents créent des problémes
      dans la partie header
    */

    return Uri.encodeComponent(value.toString());
  }```
````